# How to use SQL databases in python without writing SQL?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, orm

I'm looking for a way to use a SQL database (such as MySQL, SQLite) in python without actually writing SQL.  Example would be something like this (pseudocode):

```
# INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('John', 'Smith')
table.insert({'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith'})

# SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='John'
results = table.select({'firstname': 'John'})
print results
# [ {'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith'} ]
```

A  light wrapper around python's DB-API, or possibly a *very* lightweight ORM, would do the job for this.  If it's an ORM, it should allow mapping `namedtuple`s to the DB, since that's pretty much the only kind of object I'd want to use.  I'm sure something like this already exists, but I have trouble finding it :)

**EDIT** Some proposed solutions which aren't what I had in mind:

**SQL Alchemy**

good: the insert and select are fairly concise

bad: the objects that are stored and retrieved are not plain python dicts/namedtuples/whatever (possibly they could be made to be namedtuples, but it's not obvious how)

ugly: having to create a class for each table explicitly makes it just too heavyweight

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    ...

ed_user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', password='edspassword')
session.add(ed_user)

our_user = session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed').first() 
our_user
<User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', password='edspassword')>
```

**PonyORM**

good: the way to write queries as generators is pure genius

bad: still using custom objects, not builtin python data types

ugly: same as SQL Alchemy, need to create a class for each table

```
from pony.orm import *

db = Database()
class Person(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    age = Required(int)

p1 = Person(name='John', age=20)
commit()

persons = select(p for p in Person if p.age > 20)
```

Comment: I think [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: This list will help you - [Link](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#orm).

Comment: @pushkin: Yeah, I know about SQLAlchemy, but... look at the crazy amount of boilerplate code needed to do anything: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html  This is a lot more heavy-weight than anything I had in mind.  What I'd like is (a) the table is already created, figure out the schema from it, I don't want to write it out in code, and (b) the objects that I store or retrieve or use for lookup are just dicts, namedtuples, or whatever, definitely not any kind of object I have to explicitly create a class for.

Comment: I think what you should use is a NoSQL database instead of a relational database like MySQL. Try something like [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/). The ORMs are provided in the list provided in the previous comment.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro: This does sound a lot like MongoDB, doesn't it? :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to do some more work - by reading the documentation. SQLAlchemy has perhaps the most simplest form of "reverse engineering of the database" (called reflection), detailed [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html).

The most simple example:

```
from sqlalchemy import *

metadata = MetaData()
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')
person_table = Table('person', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
q = person_table.insert().values(name='John', age=20)
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(q)
```

Comment: Thanks, guy, but to make this work I had to change "autoload_with_engine" ->  "autoload_with"

Answer (score 2):

[dataset](https://dataset.readthedocs.io) library is good answer to your question

example:

```py
import dataset

db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///:memory:')

table = db['sometable']
table.insert(dict(name='John Doe', age=37))
table.insert(dict(name='Jane Doe', age=34, gender='female'))

john = table.find_one(name='John Doe')
```

Comment: `dataset` is cool, but it doesn't support many important SQL concepts, such as foreign keys between tables and joins.